# Client Socket Accepted Data is Different From Server Socket

Tags: java, sockets

I'm trying to simulate server - client socket connection at Java. I have that code:

```
private static Socket clientSocket;
private static PrintWriter pw;
private static Socket serverSocket;
private static final int PORT_NUMBER = 1146;

public static void init() throws IOException {
    ServerSocket sSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT_NUMBER);
    clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", PORT_NUMBER);

    serverSocket = sSocket.accept();
    OutputStream os = serverSocket.getOutputStream();
    pw = new PrintWriter(os, true);
}

private void writePackage(int[] dataPackage) {
    for (int packageByte : dataPackage) {
        pw.write(packageByte);
    }
    pw.flush();

    try {
        InputStream is = clientSocket.getInputStream();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

My data package has hexadecimal values. It is a 127 length array. When I check client input stream I see that only the first 26 elements are the ones that I wrote the output stream of the server. Others are different. i.e. 26th element is `0xC1` which is `193` in decimal but client input stream accepts is `196` in decimal.

What I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using an `OutputStream` to write binary data, not a `PrintWriter`.

Comment: You are right! Do you know that what causes the difference?